# List all other data based on a User Input using JSON and Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a JSON file which I would like to manipulate, I know this may sound basic but my question is, based on User1 + Country, how do I list all the other Users that falls under any of the listed countries based on User1

EDIT: Getting Name instead of the UserID, I realised I can't use Key,Value, how do I go around that?

```
{
    "user1":{
        "Country":[
            "China, USA, Nepal"
        ],
         "Name": [
            "Lisbon"
        ],
    },

    "user2":{
        "Country":[
            "Sweden, China, USA"
        ],
         "Name": [
            "Jade"
        ],
    },

    "user3":{
        "Country":[
            "India, China, USA"
        ],
         "Name": [
            "John"
        ],
    }
}
```

Here's what I've done so far

```
    userName= raw_input("Enter user's name: ")
    with open('listOfUsers.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for k, v in data.items():
        print str(dict[k][v])
```

Comment: That is not valid json format, and your indentation is off in your code

Comment: Edited it sir, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will do what you want:

```
def getId(name):
    for userId, v in data.items():
        if v['Name'] == name:
        return userId;

id = getId(userName)
for k, v in data.items():
    if any(x in data[id]['Country'] for x in v['Country']):
        print(k)
```

But only when you fix your json. Your lists of countries have only one string.
["China", "USA", "Nepal"] instead of ["China, USA, Nepal"]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Sir. That helped a lot! 

But what if I wanted to get the Name instead of the userID? How would I go around that?

`{
    "user1":{
        "Country":[
            "China, USA, Nepal"
        ],
      "Name": [
         "Mark"
      ]
    },

    "user2":{
        "Country":[
            "Sweden, China, USA"
        ],
      "Name": [
         "Lisbon"
      ]
    },

    "user3":{
        "Country":[
            "India, China, USA"
        ],
      "Name": [
         "Jade"
      ]
    }
}`

Comment: print(v['Name']) instead of print(k)

Comment: Thank you, that works! But the current code I'm not able to enter the User's Name(e.g. Lisbon) but instead I had to enter the UserID of Lisbon(e.g. user1). How do I go around that?

Comment: You can write a small function to get an id from json based on user's name. Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

With your json, you could do something like this using the 
[`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) method:

```
userName= raw_input("Enter user's name: ")
with open('listOfUsers.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# get username Country
user_country = data.get(username, {}).get("Country", [])[0].split()
user_country_set = set(user_country)

# then filter all users having same Country
users = [u for u, v in data.items() if set(v["Country"][0].split()).intersection(user_country_set) ]
```

But, if you can control the input json format, I would suggest using:

```
"Country":[
        "China", "USA", "Nepal"
    ]
```

instead, which would greatly simplify the code into:

```
user_country = data.get(username, {}).get("Country", [])
user_country_set = set(user_country)

# then filter all users having same Country
users = [user for user, d in data.items() if set(d.get("Country", [])).intersection(user_country_set) ]
```

Comment: What if I wanted to get the Name instead of the userID? How would I go around that?

`{
    "user1":{
        "Country":[
            "China, USA, Nepal"
        ],
      "Name": [
         "Mark"
      ]
    },

    "user2":{
        "Country":[
            "Sweden, China, USA"
        ],
      "Name": [
         "Lisbon"
      ]
    },

    "user3":{
        "Country":[
            "India, China, USA"
        ],
      "Name": [
         "Jade"
      ]
    }
}`

Comment: Try it and let me know if there is a part of the code you don't understand.

Comment: I've tried it and I would like the user to enter a User's name(e.g Lisbon) instead of entering the User ID(e.g. user1/user2 etc) and print out all the other User based on Lisbon's Country. So far the current code only allows user input to enter the UserID